# Flight "stops at Chicago" -- what does this mean?

Tags: transit, luggage, domestic-travel

I have a return ticket from New York to Los Angeles with United.  The return leg is a direct flight but the outbound leg is via Chicago. I had understood it to be a direct flight but the confirmation says "stops at Chicago", which suggests it's not a transit.  What does this mean?  Will I have to recheck my bags at Chicago or will they be transfered for me?

Comment: Is this with the same airline? Are they booked on teh same ticket (the two flights)? Have you looked at your airline's terms?

Comment: This is all with united airlines, it's the same ticket, same outbound, i have a return flight to Ny but that one's a nonstop flight so i dont have anything to worry about. This one as I understood is a direct flight and I am having trouble understanding what that means when it says "stops at chicago" meaning it's not a transit. What about my baggage ?

Answer (score 2):

If you have booked a single ticket (as opposed to two separate ones), your bags should be checked all the way through to Los Angeles. The check-in agent will tag your bags to Los Angeles when you check them in, and you won't need to pick them up in Chicago. With a little luck, they'll be waiting for you at the baggage claim in LA.

Comment: Thank you, I also have a problem understanding my flight. At first I thought it was a connecting flight , but now I am looking at my ticket and it just says "Stops at Chicago) what does that mean? Am I not going to change the aircraft? Am I going to stay in tha plane for 2,5 hours?

Comment: What are the flight numbers? Are there two separate ones listed? You will most likely be changing planes (I don't believe United runs any flights from NY to LA via Chicago where you stay on board in Chicago for hours), but I'd need to see it to be sure.

Comment: It is the same flight number, it doesn't change, it is flight n. 463, and when I purchased my ticket on my email it doesn't even mention The Chicago stop. My guess is we have to wait for other passengers to board the plane but is it really going to take 3 hours?

Comment: There aren't seperate flights listet, it just said "stops at Chicago" under the NY-LA flight, I thought we were going to have more passengers join us on the same aircraft but then I checked the time and the total trip is supposed to take 9,5 hours . That gives 3 hours in between the flights from NY-Chicago and Chicago-LA

Comment: @DianaMargaryan Ok. It looks like United uses #463 for both a LGA-ORD flight and a ORD-LAX flight, but they look like separate flights. The flights arrive and depart out of different gates in Chicago and are on different aircraft types. It's pretty much just a marketing thing to keep the same flight number, but you'll change planes in Chicago. Your bags will be checked through though.

Comment: It's a "direct flight", just with a change of planes along the way. Your bags will be checked through.